# Parsing arabic text using Sax produce?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I'm developing LWUIT project using netbeans to run on Blackberry environment. this project will read data from .net web service, I used ksoap2 and Sax Parser. Parser looks like that

```
 public static Vector ParseSAX(String input ,final String[] elements) {

    final Vector values = new Vector();

    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
              for(int u = 0;u < elements.length;u++){
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(elements[u].toString())) {
                    flag = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName) throws SAXException {
            }

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                if (flag) {
                    values.addElement(new String(ch, start, length));
                    flag  = false;
                }
            }
        };

         InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()), "UTF-8");
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        is.setCharacterStream(inputStream);
          saxParser.parse(is, handler);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return values;
}
```

I cared to parse arabic characters.

By the way, I converted the project encoding to UTF-8 and changed javac.encoding=UTF-8 in project.properties and in private.properties I added runtime.encoding=UTF-8

if I put this code in isolated project, it runs fine.

If I added in BB project or web project, will produce?

I do not know what can I do?